# vba sql query data from worksheet and external file

Tags: sql, excel, vba

is it possible to query data from a worksheet of the workbook and from an external xls file? I need to do something like this:

```
select A.col_a, B.col_b from _sheet1_ A, _extFile.sheet_ B
```

I can query an external file by using ODBC connections like "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & path_to_external_file & ";"

And I've read that I can query sheets of the same workbook by using ADO connections. But is it also possible to use both sheets in one query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can only specify ONE file in the DBQ parameter of the DSN.

One idea to do this would be to open both files via VBA, copy the entire worksheet *extFile.sheet* to the other file, save it to a (third) temporary file and THEN query that temp-file via one DSN.

Worksheet copy is possible in a single statement, so it's really not that expensive to do.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer. You are right. I've also tried it using ADODB connection but it is not possible. I bypassed the problem by merging all sources into one source.xlsx as you have proposed. thank you